# equation number to appear at center of multiline equation in the align environment

Tags: equations, align

In my code below, I wanted the last equation number to appear at the center line of the split equation, like this:

[image]

Can you assist me with this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{wnoise}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{wn}\\
y_{wn}
\end{bmatrix} & =
\left[\begin{matrix}
  (L_{1} + \delta r_{3} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}+\\
  (L_{1} + \delta r_{3} + r_{3vn})\sin\theta_{1}-
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
(\delta r_{2} + r_{2vn})\sin\theta_{1}\\
(\delta r_{2} + r_{2vn})\cos\theta_{1}
\end{matrix}\right]
+\begin{bmatrix}
v_{xn}\\
v_{yn}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{wn}\\
y_{wn}
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{xn}\\
v_{yn}
\end{bmatrix} & =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
-\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
        {\begin{bmatrix}
         \delta r_{2} \\
         \delta r_{3}
        \end{bmatrix}}+\left[\begin{matrix}
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1} +  r_{2vn}\sin\theta_{1}\\
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2vn}\cos\theta_{1}
        \end{matrix}\right]\\
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta r_{2} \\
\delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix} & =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
-\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x_{wn}\\
y_{wn}
\end{bmatrix} -
\left[\begin{matrix}
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}+ \\
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}-
        \end{matrix}\right.\right.\nonumber\\
        &\hspace{6.2cm}
\left.\left.\begin{matrix}
r_{2vn}\sin\theta_{1}\\
r_{2vn}\cos\theta_{1}
\end{matrix}\right]
- \begin{bmatrix}
v_{xn}\\
v_{yn}
\end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not split the wide matrix across two lines, but break at the multiplication, which is a more natural break point.

You can use the same idea for the different break style.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{wnoise}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{wn}\\
y_{wn}
\end{bmatrix} & =
\left[\begin{matrix}
  (L_{1} + \delta r_{3} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}+\\
  (L_{1} + \delta r_{3} + r_{3vn})\sin\theta_{1}-
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
(\delta r_{2} + r_{2vn})\sin\theta_{1}\\
(\delta r_{2} + r_{2vn})\cos\theta_{1}
\end{matrix}\right]
+\begin{bmatrix}
v_{xn}\\
v_{yn}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{wn}\\
y_{wn}
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{xn}\\
v_{yn}
\end{bmatrix} & =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
-\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta r_{2} \\
\delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}+\left[\begin{matrix}
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1} +  r_{2vn}\sin\theta_{1}\\
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2vn}\cos\theta_{1}
        \end{matrix}\right]\\
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta r_{2} \\
\delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix} & =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
   -\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
  \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\cdot{}\\
  &\qquad\qquad
   \left(
   \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{wn}\\
   y_{wn}
   \end{bmatrix} -
   \begin{bmatrix}
   (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}+r_{2vn}\sin\theta_{1}\\
   (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}-r_{2vn}\cos\theta_{1}
   \end{bmatrix} -
   \begin{bmatrix}
   v_{xn}\\
   v_{yn}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \right)
  \end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note how `split` is nested in `align` in order to have the number vertically in the middle of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

- In the *input*, I would not split parts of one and the same cell across different `matrix` environments, as doing so messes up the spacing around plus and minus symbols.
- For the line break in the third equation, do consider inserting the line break earlier, i.e., right after the 2x2 (inverted) matrix. This point is also made in egreg's answer.
- With this new choice of line break for the third equation, the equation number is best left where it is by default, i.e., centered on the second group of terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm,hmargin=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{wnoise}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{wn}\\
  y_{wn}
\end{bmatrix} 
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
     (L_{1} + \delta r_{3} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}+ 
     (\delta r_{2} + r_{2vn})\sin\theta_{1}\\
     (L_{1} + \delta r_{3} + r_{3vn})\sin\theta_{1}-
     (\delta r_{2} + r_{2vn})\cos\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
+  \begin{bmatrix}
     v_{xn}\\
     v_{yn}
   \end{bmatrix}\\
%% 2nd eq.
\begin{bmatrix}
     x_{wn}\\
     y_{wn}
\end{bmatrix}
- \begin{bmatrix}
  v_{xn}\\
  v_{yn}
\end{bmatrix} 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hfill\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
-\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
         \delta r_{2} \\
         \delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1} +  r_{2vn}\sin\theta_{1}\\
         (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2vn}\cos\theta_{1}
        \end{bmatrix}\\
%% 3rd eq.
\begin{bmatrix}
  \delta r_{2} \\
  \delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix} 
&=
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \hfill\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
  -\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \nonumber \\
&\qquad\times\left(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{wn}\\
    y_{wn}
  \end{bmatrix} -
  \begin{bmatrix}
    (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}+r_{2vn}\sin\theta_{1}\\
    (L_{1} + r_{3vn})\cos\theta_{1}-r_{2vn}\cos\theta_{1}
  \end{bmatrix}
- \begin{bmatrix}
     v_{xn}\\
     v_{yn}
  \end{bmatrix}
\right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```